# Spliting String with subelements into lines

Tags: php, regex

I want to process a string line by line, but in that string there could be some subelements which are marked by squarebracket-tags.

```
Line 1
[keyword|title|anything]
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
[end]
Line 5
Line 6
```

A formatted result could be something like:

```
<div class="element">Line 1</div>
<div class="subcat">
    <h3>title</h3>
    <div class=”element”>Line 2</div>
    <div class=”element”>Line 3</div>
    <div class=”element”>Line 4</div>
</div>
<div class=”element”>Line 5</div>
<div class=”element”>Line 6</div>
```

But a result-array (mayby multidimensional?) would also be sufficient.

**PHP:**

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);
preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $string, $matches);
```

How can I get check for the keyword in square brackets? i.e. if the keyword is “subcat”, I want to put the lines in a subcat-div, using the given title in the brackets  (like shown above)

I think I have to use RegEx to get the information out of the brackets. But how do I get the lines for the subcat?

Maybe I have to go through that string line by line. If there is a bracket with a keyword, the following lines are pushed to another array until ending-tag.
That's my theoretical idea :-)

Comment: How about moving along to JSON instead of random lines of text that are hard to parse.

Comment: From where are you getting `subcat`?

Comment: I just need to format the content shown above. So the div-elements are just an example. A result array (multidimensional or json or something else) would also be ok. I don't know how to "extract" Line 2, 3 and 5, as they are content of the square brackets. "subcat" is just an example for a keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
<?php

$string="Line 1
[subcat|title|anything]
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
[end]
Line 5
Line 6";

$string = str_replace(PHP_EOL, "#", $string);
$lines = explode("#", $string);


foreach($lines as $line)
{ 

    if (preg_match("/^\[(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\]$/",$line, $matches))
    {
        #if($matches[1] == 'subcat') 
            print '<div class="'.$matches[1].'">'
            ."\n"
            .'<h3>'.$matches[2].'</h3>'
            ."\n";
    }

    else
    {
        print '<div class="element">'.$line.'</div>'."\n";
    }
        if ($line =="[end]") 
    {   
        print "<\div>"."\n";
    }


}
?>
```